# Pick random value from JSON property

Tags: javascript, json, random

I have got a task that I described in title. I MUST NOT to use arrays, loops  and Object.keys somewhere in my code. I can only use Math.random.

**JSON file:**

```
{
  "key": "item 1, item 2, item 3",
  "key2": "abc",
  "key3": "123"
}
```

I can't even imagine how to do this without technologies that i described. If the task supported Object.keys it will be very simple (but i can't write this as answer).

**Object that i can recive from JSON:**

```
let obj = {
           key: "item 1, item 2, item 3",
           key2: "abc",
           key3: "123"
       };
```

**My function to pick random value with Object.keys (that i can't use):**

```
 let randomProperty = function (obj) { 
 let keys = Object.keys(obj);    
 return obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]]; 
};
```

JSON.stringify and parse can be used, because it must be JSON file instead object that i wrote.

Please help!

Comment: The arbitrary constraints of homework tasks make them a poor fit for SO.

Comment: Can you use Object.entries or Object.values?

Comment: I can't use Object.entries or Object.values or cycles like for in. Any work with arrays and cycles disabled.

Comment: When you say _cycles_, do you actually mean _loops_?

Comment: Does this questionable set of restrictions ban _all_ loops? Can JSON.stringify be used? Can Object.forEach used?

Comment: Are the keys of arbitrary structure or do they always follow the pattern `key${someInt}`?

Comment: This is not possible for an object whose structure (number of properties and their names) you do not know.

Comment: JSON.stringify and parse can be used, because it must be JSON file instead object that i wrote.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Variation on Ivan's answer with much less code.  [Stringify replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) counts arguments the first time, then picks one the second time.

```js
let obj = {
  key: "item 1, item 2, item 3",
  key2: "abc",
  key3: "123"
};

let k, n = 0;
JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => (key && ++n || value));
n *= Math.random();
JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => (key && --n | 0 || (k = key) || value));
console.log(obj[k]);
```

Comment: Full disclosure: I find this to be pointless, but slightly entertaining.

Comment: Note: This will properly handle a value of `["1", "2", "3"]`, while my answer will not. I'd accept this answer.

Comment: What about nested objects? AFAIR, we will get their keys in transformer, but we should not be selecting them according to problem description.

Comment: @IvanKoshelev, I admit that the condition is challenging to understand, but if you examine it, you'll see that it only returns `value` if the key is falsy (recall that the root object is processed with an empty string as its key), so it only expands the root object for serialization.  Nested objects will technically be serialized as their key -- the result of the serialization is discarded though, so it doesn't matter anyway.  We're really only using `JSON.stringify` to _cheat_ and use its ability to discern the keys and to loop.

Comment: @Wyck Ok, i see it now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this violate any of the rules set?

**Update** made it not use square brackets, as requested. You could also possibly use a built-in JS [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with its `.get` and `.set` methods.
P.S. I'm not sure who gave you this task, but it is something that definitely has no place in a normal JS course.

```
let obj = {
    key: "item 1, item 2, item 3",
    key2: "abc",
    key3: "123"
};

function get(obj, key) {
    // JS runtime can compile functions on the fly.
    // This allows to access keys with names known at runtime without square brackets
    const getter = new Function('x', `return x.${key}`);
    return getter(obj);
}

function set(obj, key, value) {
    const setter = new Function('x', 'y', `return x.${key} = y;`);
    setter(obj, value);
}

let count = 0;
let indexToKeysDict = {};
JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, val) {
    if (key && this === obj) {
        // keys can't start with number, so we add 'a' 
        set(indexToKeysDict, `a${count}`, key);
        count++;
    }
    return val;
});

console.log(`Array.isArray(indexToKeysDict) = ${Array.isArray(indexToKeysDict)}`); // to avoid any question about using arrays

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

const index = getRandomInt(0, count);
const key = get(indexToKeysDict, `a${index}`);
console.log(get(obj, key));
```

Comment: That's worked, but even square brackets from arrays can't be set. I also need to parse similar JSON file like this, because originally task sounds like "transfer JSON into object without "arrays, loops, Object.keys".

Comment: Is `JSON.parse` allowed?

Comment: JSON.parse allowed

Comment: So this is now becoming an underhanded js contest for hiding loops?

Comment: @Bergi Or we are helping someone circumvent a naive regex-based system for sanitizing submittable JS code ;-}

Comment: @Diana-Hayes i added the no-square-brackets version as requested. Also, as some people noted, the nature of this problem makes it not very suitable for Stackoverflow, more like something to discuss over on Reddit and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) to turn the object into a string. Then, the goal is to [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) up just the keys and values into an array that we can work with and get rid of everything else. Use [`slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) to get rid of the leading `{` and trailing `}`. Get rid of the colons and commas by [replacing](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) them with some unique string ("DELIM" in my example), and then `split` by that string to get our array.

Once that's done, we just have to pick a random *odd* index, which will point to a value. To do this, pick a number from 0 through one less than half of the array with `Math.floor(Math.random() * (keysAndValuesArray.length / 2))` (remember, Math.random() never returns exactly one, and Math.floor() will bring the result down, not up). Then, we multiply that number by two to get a random even number pointing to a key in our array and add 1 to get our random odd number pointing to a value in our array.

After that, all that's left is to grab the value from the array we created at the index we picked and [`JSON.parse`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) it to get the raw value.

Please note that this isn't a perfect solution because values in the object that contain the strings we're trying to split by (`":` and `","`) could throw things off.

```js
var obj = {
  key: "item 1, item 2, item 3",
  key2: "abc",
  key3: 123
};

var keysAndValuesArray = JSON.stringify(obj).slice(1, -1).replace(/":/g, "\"DELIM").replace(/","/g, "\"DELIM\"").split("DELIM");
var randomOddIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (keysAndValuesArray.length / 2)) * 2 + 1;
console.log(keysAndValuesArray[randomOddIndex]);
```